# How to create a django formset or form add/edit page in order to edit several records

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

For one of my open source projects, I need to create ONE add/edit page in order to make possible to edit several records with one save.

The repo is an IMDB clone formed for learning purpose. A user can add her/his favorite genres in her/his profile. Then an edit page is formed to show the list of those favored genres and the movies within that genre. (A for loop here) User can add notes, watch list options and so on to those movies. (NOT a FORMSET)

However, the code doesn't work as expected. The page cannot be saved and only the first checkbox of the list can be changed.

There is no error.

NOTE:

- You can install repo with dummy data.
  (https://github.com/pydatageek/imdb-clone)
- Then after logging in, select your favorite genres. (http://localhost:8000/users/profile/)
- Then (I wish it can be solved here) you can see the movies with your selected genres. Add notes, to watch list... (http://localhost:8080/users/profile/movies2/)

```
# users/templates/user-movies-with_loop.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!-- Title -->
{% block htitle %}Your movies from favorite genres{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Your movies from favorite genres{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="card card-signin">
  {% include 'users/profile-menu.html' %}
  <h3 class="card-title text-center my-4">Take notes for your movies <small></small></h3>
  <hr class="mb-1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for genre in user.genres.all %}
        <h2 for="genre" name="genre" value="{{ genre.id }}">{{ genre.name }}</h2>
        {% for movie in genre.movies.all %}
          <div class="ml-5">
            <h4>{{ movie.title }}</h4>
            {{ form|crispy }}  
          </div>      
          <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ user.id }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="movie" value="{{ movie.id }}">

        {% empty %}
        <p class="alert alert-danger">The genre you have selected on your profile doesn't have any movies!</p>
        {% endfor %}  
      {% empty %}

      <p class="alert alert-danger">You should select genres with movies from your profile to edit here!</p>
      {% endfor %}

      <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

```
# users.forms.py
...
class UserMovieFormWithLoop(ModelForm):
    genre = forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'disabled': True})
    class Meta:
        model = UserMovie
        fields = ('user', 'movie', 'note', 'watched', 'watch_list')
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.HiddenInput,
            'movie': forms.HiddenInput,
            'watched': forms.CheckboxInput(),
        }
...
```

```
# users.models.py
...
class UserMovie(models.Model):
    """
        Users have notes about their favorite movies.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey('movies.Movie', default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    watched = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Have you seen before?')
    watch_list = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Add to Watch List?')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} ({self.movie.title})'
...
```

```
# users.views.py
...
class UserMovieViewWithLoop(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserMovie
    template_name = 'users/user-movies-with_loop.html'
    form_class = UserMovieFormWithLoop
    success_message = 'your form has been submitted.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:user_movies2')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = self.request.user
        movie_counter = Movie.objects.filter(genres__in=user.genres.all()).count()
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.user = user
        for i in range(movie_counter):
            f.pk = None
            f.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):      
        context = super(UserMovieViewWithLoop, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return UserMovie.objects.get(user=user)
...
```

Comment: In the best manners, I don't think anyone will bother cloning the repo and testing it to locate the bug. You should ideally provide the relevant code that you think likely to be the cause and then we can look into it :)

Comment: Indeed, I have provided the code, but installing it from repo with dummy data takes only 3-4 min. so I have put the link for people who would like to see the application in action. thank you.